# HDR and Alpha Blending

Tags: 3d, graphics, graphics-programming

I've been reading a lot about HDR techniques and came across Alpha Blending compatibility. Searched even more and found this snippet from the Ogre Forums:

> With source alpha blending, it sometimes looks ok provided the range differences aren't too high, but most other blend modes fail completely, particularly add. You really have to do your own separate composition in another fragment shader targetting a second texture and pulling the 'background' values in so you can do accurate blending, rather than render the transparent effects into the same original surface.

Why is alpha blending an issue when it comes to rendering HDR (values above 1.0) in 16FP FrameBuffers?

Answer (score 2):

The source post says it all.

http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=41811

> Blending in *fake HDR* is tough, because the frame buffer blend cannot cater for **the *exponent* you're storing in the *alpha channel***

Fake HDR, exponent, alpha channel. It only matters for a specific HDR format where, as mentioned above, ..

> "Fake" HDR, where the alpha channel is used as a scalar/exponent value to simulate high dynamic range

So alpha blending is not the issue. The issue is that a color surface is used for unintended purposes and only in that case, alpha blending fails.

Comment: I am not using the alpha channel for color multiplication, instead a factor is used only on a fragments RGB, alpha is intact.

Comment: For alpha blending, alpha is necessary for the factor because there's no other way to multiply it to the destination color. But there's nothing to worry about with FP16 framebuffers.